# Precision on XAML DEBUG

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-store-apps

I need a few explaination about how this exception is rised :

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Is there a way to get a more accurate error ?

Why could this kind of ambigus error rised ?

Comment: This is not part of a "classic" WPF app. This looks like some Windows Store app generated code. Are you sure of your question tags here?

Comment: You're right ... Monday morning you know :/ ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why could this kind of ambigus error rised ?

If the application code throws an exception that isn't caught properly by your exception handling code, the exception will propagate back to the Windows Runtime. The Windows Runtime will then fire the `UnhandledException` event to notify the app of this exception.

> Is there a way to get a more accurate error ?

If you take a look at the `e` parameter, which is a `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs`, you'll see the exact exception that was originally thrown, the associated error message and the position in code where the error occurred. This is a good start to find what happened. If it happens to be unsufficient, next step is to implement logging in your application.